# Time-Based Data Filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, filtering

Say I have a data frame given by-

```
dic = {'firstname':['John','John','John','John','John','Susan','Susan',
                    'Susan','Susan','Susan','Mike','Mike','Mike','Mike',
                    'Mike'],
       'lastname':['Smith','Smith','Smith','Smith','Smith','Wilson',
                   'Wilson','Wilson','Wilson','Wilson','Jones','Jones',
                   'Jones','Jones','Jones'],
       'company':['KFC','BK','KFC','KFC','KFC','MCD','MCD','WND','WND',
                  'WND','TB','TB','TB','CHP','TB'],
       'worked':['2020-03-12','2020-09-19','2020-03-14','2020-05-10',
                 '2020-03-20','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2020-03-13',
                 '2020-06-09','2020-06-16','2020-12-3','2020-11-29',
                 '2020-09-17','2020-12-4','2020-12-9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)
```

and the output is-

```
   firstname lastname company      worked
0       John    Smith     KFC  2020-03-12
1       John    Smith      BK  2020-09-19
2       John    Smith     KFC  2020-03-14
3       John    Smith     KFC  2020-05-10
4       John    Smith     KFC  2020-03-20
5      Susan   Wilson     MCD  2020-01-05
6      Susan   Wilson     MCD  2020-01-05
7      Susan   Wilson     WND  2020-03-13
8      Susan   Wilson     WND  2020-06-09
9      Susan   Wilson     WND  2020-06-16
10      Mike    Jones      TB   2020-12-3
11      Mike    Jones      TB  2020-11-29
12      Mike    Jones      TB  2020-09-17
13      Mike    Jones     CHP   2020-12-4
14      Mike    Jones      TB   2020-12-9
```

I want to narrow down my results to ensure that a person worked at a company at least 2 times. I also got the proper date format and sorted the dates.

As a result-

```
df['worked'] = pd.to_datetime(df['worked'])
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['firstname','lastname','company'],keep=False)]
df = df.sort_values(['firstname','lastname','company','worked'])
print(df)
```

with output-

```
   firstname lastname company     worked
0       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-12
2       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-14
4       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-20
3       John    Smith     KFC 2020-05-10
12      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-09-17
11      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-11-29
10      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-03
14      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-09
5      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
6      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
7      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-03-13
8      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-06-09
9      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-06-16
```

Using this new data frame, how can I narrow it down even further to return only values where these people worked within 7 days of their last work day?

I also had a suggested answer of-

```
c1 = df.duplicated(['firstname','lastname','company'],keep=False)
c2 = df.groupby(['firstname','lastname'])['worked'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).le(7) 
out = df[c1 & c2]
print(out)
```

With output-

```
   firstname lastname company     worked
0       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-12
2       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-14
4       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-20
12      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-09-17
10      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-03
14      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-09
5      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
6      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
7      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-03-13
9      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-06-16
```

However, my desired output is-

```
   firstname lastname company     worked
0       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-12
2       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-14
4       John    Smith     KFC 2020-03-20
11      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-11-29
10      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-03
14      Mike    Jones      TB 2020-12-09
5      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
6      Susan   Wilson     MCD 2020-01-05
8      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-06-09
9      Susan   Wilson     WND 2020-06-16
```

(Indexes 3, 12, and 7 would be filtered out of my desired final output because they are not within 7 days of another day worked by a certain person with a certain company.)

Hope my question makes sense, and any help is appreciated.